# Eligibility for TWOV while flying Air Asia, transferring at KLIA2

Tags: visas, transit, malaysia, kul

We are a family of 3 Indian citizens with Indian passports travelling Mumbai-Sydney-Mumbai via Kuala Lumpur in April 2018. We have valid Australia tourist visas stamped on our Indian passports. On the Mumbai-Sydney sector, I have direct Fly-thru status, so just flight change as International Transfer without immigration, no Malaysian visa requured.

However, due to Air Asia's rescheduling the flights, on the return journey, my flights have a layover of 25 hours. Can you confirm whether I would be eligible for transit without visa at  KLIA2 on arrival from Sydney? Arriving from Sydney at 6 pm on 28-4-2018, and flying out to to Mumbai, India, on 29-4-2018 at 7 pm.

Answer (score 3):

Checking via Timatic, courtesy of the [Emirates visa check](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx) and the [KLIA2 Airport visa information](http://www.klia2.info/trips/malaysia/malaysia-visa-information) confirms that you do not need a visa to transit, as you meet one, or more, of the conditions.

> **4. Transit Without Visa (TWOV)**
>
> The Transit Without Visa (TWOV) is only applicable after clearing Malaysian Immigration - for a maximum of 120 hours stop-over in Malaysia. However, granting of TWOV is solely at the discretion of the Malaysia Immigration; even if guest(s) meet all the required criteria.
>
> **Countries eligible for Transit Without Visa: Indian Subcontinent** (for holders of Diplomatic & Official Passports)**
>
> - Sri Lanka
> - India
> - Pakistan
> - Bangladesh
>
> **Eligibility**
>
> - Onward ticket must be within 120 hours.
> - Must arrive and depart only via the same airport. (e.g. Arrive in KLIA2, Depart from KLIA2)
> - Possess a valid onward ticket and carry a Single Entry Visa (SEV) or Multiple Entry Visa (MEV) issued from/and are heading to any one (1) of the seven (7) countries listed below (*TWOV will not be issued if next country of destination is not listed as above):
> - Australia
> - New Zealand
> - United States of America (USA)
> - Japan
> - China
> - Taiwan
> - South Korea
> - Passport MUST have a minimum validity of 6 months.
> - A PRINTED copy of itinerary and original tickets MUST be produced. Producing only a PNR/booking number will be denied access.

Comment: Does the "Diplomatic & Official Passports only" refer only to citizens of Bangladesh?

Comment: @mdd It's difficult to tell. Even the official website is unclear on this point.